# ignite ui date picker scroll is not working for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ignite-ui

I am using the datepicker of ignite UI but when I select the year range I am not able to scoll in mobile but working fine in desktop version.

```
 <div class="field-label">Date of Birth</div>
          <igx-date-picker 
            #datePicker
            type="border"
            class="form-field"
            [maxValue]="today"
            formControlName="dob">
          </igx-date-picker>
        </div>
```

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0piy.png)

Can anyone help with fix if you faced the similar issue.

I am trying to put a scroll but all the dates are not loaded by default as virtual scroll is implemented.